# How to install wireless-tools exclusively from command line?

Tags: command-line

How may I install [wireless-tools](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/8.0/basicnet/wireless_tools.html) in Ubuntu 16.10 just using the command line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*wireless-tools* is installed by default in Ubuntu 16.10. Verify:

```
sudo dpkg -s wireless-tools
```

You should see *Status: install ok installed*

If not, install with:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install wireless-tools
```